# Python behavior

Tags: python, windows, list, process

I did a simple test, I tried to take square of numbers till 50.000.Using Python 3.4.

First I tried;

```
num=range(1,50000)
sq=lambda x:x**2
print (list(map(sq,num)))
```

I got error that is *Python stop working*.

Then I tried;

```
sqlist=[]
for x in range(1,50000):
    sq=x**2
    sqlist.append(sq)
print (sqlist)
```

I got same error again,stop working.

Then I tried it with *while* loop;

```
sqlist=[]
t=1
while t<50001:
    t+=1
    sq=t**2
    sqlist.append(sq)
print (sqlist)
```

Again same error, but *while* loop clearly survived more than *for* loop.

Last test I do is;

```
sqlist=[]
sqlist1=[]
sqlist2=[]
sqlist3=[]
sqlist4=[]
t=1
while t<50001:
    t+=1
    sq=t**2
    if t<10000:
        sqlist.append(sq)
    elif t<20000:
        sqlist1.append(sq)
    elif t<30000:
        sqlist2.append(sq)
    elif t<40000:
        sqlist3.append(sq)
    elif t<50000:
        sqlist4.append(sq)

print (sqlist,sqlist1,sqlist2,sqlist3,sqlist4)
```

And I got what I want, no error,shows me squares of numbers till 50,000. I did this with *for* loop too, and *while* loop was clearly faster than *for* loop again.

> So why *while* loop is faster than *for* loop and why need bunch of lists? Why a single list throwing error?Also last way has more process than others, more codes more things to check etc.

Comment: First of all, its weird that you got the error on your first three examples, since they should works with no issues. I tested them and they work. You might have some issues with your Python on your machine...

Comment: You should post the full Error Traceback.

Comment: Although the `append()` operation [has O(1) complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), the notes mention that *individual actions may take surprisingly long, depending on the history of the container.* I suspect appending to the same list over and over again will end up spending a lot of time reallocating memory and copying data. This may explain why using several lists appears to be more efficient.

Comment: @KlausD. I said, _Python stop working_ thats the error.

Comment: @qwerty: you are using Windows? Im sorry about that :) Can you run your script from the console?

Comment: @Lawrence thats weird, I tried it on cmd now and all ways are working with no error.But its throwing error when I try to process with Python. So is _cmd_ > _PythonShell_? :)

Comment: You are talking about IDLE i presume? I guess its not optimized memory wise for such operations. Hardly anyone uses IDLE anyway, use shell or cmd or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using IDLE. IDLE doesn't work well with large amounts of text (AFAIK this is a problem with Tk). Just don't print the list.

To view the list, you could instead write the list to a file.

```
with open("squareslist.txt") as f:
    f.write(str(sqlist))
```

And then you could view the squareslist.txt file in a text editor such as Notepad.

Or you could view the individual elements of the list, e.g.

```
print(sqlist[13])
```

Comment: IDLE definitely cannot handle *printing* large amounts of anynything.